# How to get bson_t* subdocument from bson_iter_t using C API

Tags: c, mongodb, bson

I am using mongoc and associated BSON library for reading and writing to a disk file. I'm having trouble understanding the BSON C API. This is for an acceptance test where I have expected results saved in a binary file (generated using `bson_writer_*` functions). The binary-to-ascii dump of the file looks reasonable.

Now I want to read that file, presumably using `bson_reader_*`. I am following the [sparse] documentation, and can get a BSON document with the following (error checking removed for clarity):

```
bool foundEOF;
bson_error_t error;
const char* file_name = "expected_results.dat";

bson_reader_t *reader = bson_reader_new_from_file (file_name, &error)
const bson_t *doc = bson_reader_read (reader, &foundEOF);
```

So far so good. Now I want to look for specific entries and pull out the values:

```
bson_iter_t iter;
bson_iter_init_find(&iter, doc, "my_key"); 
const bson_value_t *value = bson_iter_value (&iter);
```

I know that the value of `my_key` entry is itself a BSON subdocument. But *how do I get a `bson_t*` pointer to that subdocument so that I can work with it?* All I have here is a `bson_value_t*` that I can't figure out what to do with.

I was hoping it was similar to `mongo_cursor_t` where I could "iterate" through a collection like this to get subdocuments:

```
const bson_t* subdoc = nullptr;
mongo_cursor_next(cursor, subdoc);
```

but I don't see how to get a `bson_t*` subdocument from a BSON document using the BSON API. What am I missing?

Comment: It sort of looks like `bson_value_t` *is* the sub document.  [Here](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_value_t.html) is the definition of that type.

Comment: In my code, I have a factory method that creates C++ objects given a `bson_t*`. I want to iterate over the larger document and pull out the subdocs as `bson_t*` that I can then pass to the factory method to get the corresponding instances. I can't do anything with `bson_value_t*` though. I don't see any class relationship to cast between the two.